# Curl command for creating Github Repository is not working

Tags: json, github, curl, github-api, github-api-v3

I tried the following code for creating a repository. But it gives JSON parsing problem. What causes this?. I took this code from https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos  tried in python code using requests.post method. But that too gave the same error `Problem Parsing JSON`. Is this bad request or the parsing problem is inside Github API.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token MYACCESSTOKENHERE" \
    -d '{ \
        "name": "simp", \
        "auto_init": true, \
        "private": true, \
        "gitignore_template": "nanoc" \
      }' \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 05:14:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 159
Server: GitHub.com
Status: 400 Bad Request
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4956
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1596950918
X-OAuth-Scopes: admin:gpg_key, admin:org, admin:org_hook, admin:repo_hook, gist, notifications, read:packages, repo, user, workflow, write:discussion, write:packages
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
X-GitHub-Request-Id: B649:25C9:CDEF3A:117E0EE:5F2F862F

{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please validate your token is authorized.
Please refer [Authorizing OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps)

```
curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" <https://<your_repo_endpoint> -I
```

Update using JSON formatter

```
"-d""{ \\
        \"name\": \"simp\", \\
        \"auto_init\": true, \\
        \"private\": true, \\
        \"gitignore_template\": \"nanoc\" \\
      }""\\
```

Comment: The token I use is not the problem, otherwise, it would have pointed out that authorization error. But the problem is in the body of JSON.

Comment: @RNanthak  have tried using a JSON parser to see the formatting and found it like below        "-d""{ \\
        \"name\": \"simp\", \\
        \"auto_init\": true, \\
        \"private\": true, \\
        \"gitignore_template\": \"nanoc\" \\
      }""\\

Comment: Thanks @albertsebastian. I found it. Now I used ```curl -i -H "Authorization: token 1f003ae8eab2feea72630d6f3150b921a522a868" -d '{ "name": "simp1", "private": true}' https://api.github.com/user/repos```. After removing the unnecessary lines it worked.

Comment: Hi @RNanthak Happy to hear back from you that you have figured out the right format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the JSON format. After I removed unwanted lines and spaces from the curl command, it worked.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token 1f003ae8eab2feea72630d6f3150b921a522a868" -d '{ "name": "simp1", "private": true}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```